# AWK command to separate line using Field-sperator

Tags: bash, shell, awk

```
 Info 750: local macro 'ADD_GEN_METHOD' (line 149, file /home/vya3kor/vmshare/vya3kor_rbin_g3g_tas_lcmccatestadapter.vws/di_cfc/components/spm/LcmProject/framework/cca/server/generic/spm_CcaServiceHandlerFiParamConfig.cpp) not referenced
```

I want to separate above line using awk with field-separator `(line`

I used this command but it's not working

```
$ grep Info.* 1.txt |awk -F "(line" '{print $1}'
error : awk: fatal: Unmatched ( or \(: /(line/
```

output I want:

```
/di_cfc/components/spm/LcmProject/framework/cca/server/generic/spm_CcaServiceHandlerFiParamConfig.cpp%149%Info 750%local macro 'ADD_GEN_METHOD'%
```

So I used this command :

```
$ grep  '^[Ii]nfo.*:'|
awk -F ":" '{print $1"%" $2}'| 
awk -F ", file.*.vws" '{print $1"%" $2 }'| 
awk -F ") not referenced" '{print $1"%" }'|
awk -F '(' '{print $1"%" $2"%" $3}'|
awk -F "line" '{print $1 $2 $3 }' | 
awk -F "%" '{print $1$ "\n2" $3 $4 $4 $5}'
```

Comment: What output do you expect to have for that input line?

Comment: That didn't help at all. Update the post.

Comment: @user2713375 Stop posting code in comments, and edit the question with this information.

Comment: Still entirely unhelpful. Comments can't do meaningful formatting. Edit your post with the data so you can format it sanely.

Comment: I edited your question to format it. You are completely missing the point of using awk AND the error message told you exactly what your specific problem was. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -F '\\(line' '{print $1}'
Info 750: local macro ADD_GEN_METHOD
```

`(` is special regex symbol that needs to be escaped.

Comment: The quotes matter. Single vs. double.

Comment: @EtanReisner for double quote `awk -F "\\\(line" '{print $1}'`. So I would say that the `[(]` is a better solution, since it will be the same for both single and double quote.

Answer (score 2):

instead of escaping the `(`, you can do in this way:

```
awk -F'[(]line' '... your codes'
```

personally I think it is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use three backslashes if the Field Seperator was set through `-v`,

```
$ echo 'Info 750: local macro 'ADD_GEN_METHOD' (line 149, file /home/vya3kor/vmshare/vya3kor_rbin_g3g_tas_lcmccatestadapter.vws/di_cfc/components/spm/LcmProject/framework/cca/server/generic/spm_CcaServiceHandlerFiParamConfig.cpp) not referenced' | awk -v FS="\\\(line" '{print $1}'
Info 750: local macro ADD_GEN_METHOD
```

Answer (score 0):

With all that chopping, you may be better off with `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^[Ii]nfo/s/\(Info.*\): \([^(]*\).*file \([^)]*)\) .*/\3%\1%\2/gp' 1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
Info 750: local macro 'ADD_GEN_METHOD' (line 149, file /home/vya3kor/vmshare/vya3kor_rbin_g3g_tas_lcmccatestadapter.vws/di_cfc/components/spm/LcmProject/framework/cca/server/generic/spm_CcaServiceHandlerFiParamConfig.cpp) not referenced
$
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS=" *[()] *"; OFS="%" }
/^[Ii]nfo.*:/ {
    split($2,a,/[ ,]+/)
    sub(/: /,OFS,$1)
    sub(/.*\.vws/,"",$2)
    print $2, a[2], $1 OFS
}
$
$ awk -f tst.awk file
/di_cfc/components/spm/LcmProject/framework/cca/server/generic/spm_CcaServiceHandlerFiParamConfig.cpp%149%Info 750%local macro 'ADD_GEN_METHOD'%
$
```

or you could do it all in GNU awk with one gensub() call or just use sed as @chthonicdaemon suggested since this is just a simple substitution on a single line.